# Using specific gpg key in ssh_config

Tags: ssh, gpg, gpg-agent

I have multiple GPG keys. One of them I use on daily basis, signing commits, e-mails and such, it is on my computers and ready at hand. I have a different key that I consider more trustworthy, I use it to encrypt confidential information, it is offline in Yubikey and I have to plug it in whenever I want to use it.

For both of those keys I have authentication subkeys. Again, divided by trustworthiness. I can use my "on computer" key to push to github, but to login to my salt-master, I need the offline key.

Now, what I'm struggling with is that I would like to have on most of my servers possibility to use both - just in case if I would loose the less trustworthy key and sometimes I need to access the same server using multiple keys. Like gitolite admin vs user.

Now my problem is I don't know which key ssh picks to try first, so sometimes I'm asked to insert Yubikey when pushing, but more importantly, I haven't figured out how to handle Gitolite usecase.

I can put into my `.ssh/config` different *Host* entries for the same server, same user just different key and that works great if using ssh keys that are located somewhere on the disk, but can't figure out how to enter there specific gpg key provided by `gpg-agent`. Is there some solution, or do I have no other choice but to revert back to using ssh keys?

Comment: Run your ssh with -vvv to get verbose output. In that output it should give information about what methods of authentication it is using and the specific keys chosen.

`ssh -vvv username@hostname`

Comment: Yes, that told me:
`Server accepts key: (none) ED25519 SHA256:X............U agent`
But unfortunately I still have no idea how to enter it into _Host_ section in `.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 0):

On ~/.ssh/config file, Add a public key instead private.
You can make a public key by `gpg --export-ssh-key`.
SSH will try all key that listed on ssh-add -l, and it will pick a first key.
You can check a log using -vT option.

Export your authentication flag toggled gpg key

```
Match host company.github.com exec CMD
    Hostname github.com
    ...
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/company.pub

Match host my.github.com exec CMD
    Hostname github.com
    ...
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/me.pub
```

Comment: How does substituting a *public* key for a private one help?

Comment: Well. In my case, I have a two personal account on github.

Comment: I wanted to make my gpg replace all related on authentication such as code server ssh connection and git clone.
This can be done just simply add a gpg keygrip on sshcontrol file. But same domain, different account using different key configuration not work because agent always tried authentication only first record on the ssh control file. When using ssh key, i can specify certain key using IdentityFile option but in case of gpg, it doesn't have private key in ssh form. So, instead of private key, using public key make do the trick